# Undo Location Services consent

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, location-services

I wanted to see whether WiFi-assisted GPS gave me better results indoors than GPS alone, so I went to Settings > Location > Mode and selected "High accuracy" instead of "Device only".

This prompted me to turn on Location Services and give Google access to my location at all times, which I don't really want to do long-term, but I allowed it to see what happened.

My GPS was no better, so I set my phone back to "Device only" mode. However, a couple of things have changed now which makes me suspicious that *Google still thinks it has my permission to use Location Services to get my position*:

- If I select "High accuracy" again, I do not get another permission request.
- If I turn Location off completely and back on again, it defaults to "High accuracy".
- The Location icon is permanently in my status bar; it used to go away when not using e.g. Maps.

How can I rescind the permission I gave for Location Services to track my position, and get back to the state my phone was before?

Edit: I have a Moto X Play, stock ROM (pretty much vanilla Android 6.0.1).

Comment: On my S5, under settings there's a 'Google' control panel, which has some separate settings for GPS use. That might be able to get what you want done.

Comment: @MichaelKohne If I go to Settings > Google, the only obvious option is Location, which takes me to the same Location settings page as I was using before.

Comment: coincidence - same device,same android version, , Build MPD24.107-52, security patch level 01 Mar 16. I tried what you did and don't see what you see except for the last bullet

Comment: I've seen this concern a lot of times in different places (e.g. at XDA). It seems Google "accidentally" forgot that part, and the only way back is a factory-reset.

Comment: @beeshyams "coincidence"?

Comment: coincidence that we both should be having the same device and OS- anyway, Izzy has pointed you to a solution

Comment: @beeshyams hah OK, I thought you meant coincidence that I started seeing different behaviour after I did what I did... I'll hold out for a less blunt-instrument solution for a little longer.